# how much do I need to know Java before I begin JSP?

Tags: jsp

I'm not a total beginner in Java, but I just don't know the skills I need to make a jump to JSP. I have been programming with PHP for a few months now.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are doing with JSP.  To do any of the business logic will require you to know java.

It would be like knowing just how to use `echo` in PHP and doing the html/css/javascript.  You can get some done, but that means that someone else will have done the work of creating the rest of the php code to go to the database or any other resource.

If you are going to just be a UI designer then you may want to look at some of the frameworks, such as JavaServer Faces, and see if that will help you.

Ultimately, to do anything useful you will need to learn Java though, how much, and what parts depends on what it is you are doing.

Comment: sounds like a lot...i am planning to create web apps with jsp or i can say i want to create complete sites with it. e-commerce, web services, database-driven apps and a lot more. I have touched on j2se but not on j2ee; how is j2ee related to jsp anyway?

Comment: JSP is somewhat contained within J2EE spec, but ideally, you may want to look at the Spring Framework, as it will make much of the J2EE parts easier, IMO.  You will need to learn much of Java to do what you mentioned here.

Comment: hope I can do it fast. I started a little of basic PHP last April and after a week or two I immediately went with Codeigniter and Kohana. I can't remember much about my j2se programming back in my college days though:(

Comment: Try Netbeans and Eclipse, and determine which IDE will help you the most, initially, and just start on the user interface. You may want to experiment with Javaserver faces and some other web frameworks, and see which seems most natural to you. I actually liked the beehive framework when I used it years ago. It compiles to struts, so I had the power of struts without learning the framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use JSP as if it were old-school PHP, you'd be up to speed after a day or two.

If you want to buy into something "enterpise"-like JBoss, etc, you'll need a long time.  (I think I just threw up in my mouth...)

What's your motivation from "jumping to" JSP.  (I'm not sure it's a jump in the right direction...).

Comment: hm...i read a book on UML designing (Apress Use-Case Driven Object Modeling) but unofrtunately I wasn't able to apply it to PHP because code samples were using JSP with concepts of JDBC and JSTL. I want to construct my websites with UML so I want to start JSP (not that I'm saying that one cannot use UML for PHP)

Comment: UML?  Oh, you are gonna LOVE the enterprise culture of Java.  I think are programming temperments are real different.  You should ignore any advice I give you (except the advice to ignore the advice I give you).

Comment: by the way...how is JSP related to J2EE?

Comment: JSP is pretty much like the Php "bit" of the whole Java side of things - i.e. it lets you put code in the webpage and dynamically generate Html etc. J2EE is the php interpretation engine equivalent, i.e. mod_php in Apache and all the associated php plugins you can load to extend the available functionality in php.

Answer (score 0):

Just start with a small fun project and see where you hitting walls. Then try to figure out how to resolve the problems. For your second project you will know how to start to avoid these problems.

I would recommend to get a good reference book that introduces you to the whole java web programming culture, if you really want to get started with that.

You should be able to convert the UML and the constructs used there into something you can use with PHP and maybe thats the way to ge before you start to use another big big monster.